# How to scale a background image in a div responsively to the screen size

Tags: html, css, screen, responsive

I'd like to add a background-image to my website inside a div that should resizes perfectly on all devices. I tried the simplest way like "height: 100%" but that didn't work at all. I also tried media-queries which of course works but is rather complicated so I wanted to ask if there is an easier way to solve this.

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="bg"></div>
```

And that's the CSS

```
.bg {
    background: url('bg.jpg') no-repeat center cover;
}
```

Comment: How do you mean 'resize perfectly on all devices?' - devices have different aspect ratios.

Comment: Yeah that's the point. Isn't there a simple way to let the background-image resize itself independent of the screen size of the device?

Comment: I'll elaborate...How do you want a landscape photo to look on a mobile in portrait mode? Do you want it to cover the entire screen and be centred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Sqnkov has the right answer. An empty div will work with that set up.

Try running the code below and see. (Make it full page and resize the browser).
The `center center` makes in centered in the Y and X axis.  `background-size: cover;` makes the image cover all available space. If you want to make sure the entire image is in view, use `background-size: contain;` instead.

```css
body{
  margin: 0; /* Stripping out margin and padding so .bg can be full width*/
  padding: 0;
}
.bg {
  box-sizing: border-box; /*Not necessary in this situation*/
  display: block; /*Not necessary, but we do want it this way*/
  width: 100vw;  /*Not necessary, but we do want it this way*/
  height: 100vh; /*Necessary.  100vh = 100% of the viewport height*/
  padding: 0; /* No padding */
  margin: 0; /* No margins */
  background: url('https://images6.alphacoders.com/405/405948.jpg') no-repeat center center;  
  /* Shorthand: image, repeat, X align, Y align. */
  background-size: cover; /* Cover all available space*/
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Alternatively, if you specify that the parent containers' (`html, body`) height and width as 100% you can use `100%` height/width instead of `100vh/vw` on the child `.bg` container as percentages are relative to the parent container.

See the example below:

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0; /* Stripping out margin and padding so .bg can be full width*/
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;  /*Setting parent width -- child width is relative*/
  height: 100%; /*Setting parent height -- child height is relative*/
}
.bg {
  box-sizing: border-box; /*Not necessary in this situation*/
  display: block; /*Not necessary, but we do want it this way*/
  width: 100%;  
  height: 100%; /* Now 100% height will work */
  padding: 0; /* No padding */
  margin: 0; /* No margins */
  background: url('https://images6.alphacoders.com/405/405948.jpg') no-repeat center center;  
  /* Shorthand: image, repeat, X align, Y align. */
  background-size: cover; /* Cover all available space*/
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: No problem! It's easier to visualize it when you can run it :D  I really like that SO let's us embed code snippets. Anyway, if this answered your question you can mark this as solved by accepting an answer *wink-wink* ;p

Answer (score 1):

I'm still learning myself, but have you tried "background-size: cover;" in your CSS?

See more info here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp.

Answer (score 1):

Simply apply a size preference to your background property. Here is a shorthand usage:

> ***This is a setting for a big background image that fills its parent to the borders.***

`background: url('images/image.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;`

Which is equal to:

```
background-image: url('images/image.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
```

I suggest giving **[this MDN thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)** a read.

Comment: Thank you. But is does it make a difference when my background-image is inside a div? Because the background is only shown when something is **inside** the dive like a text. But I want the background-image scaled to the screen size independent wether there is content inside the div or not.

Comment: Yes but like I said, the background-image is inside a div. Does this make any difference?

Comment: You mean the actual image file is in the markup inside the div - `<div> <img src=".." /> </div>` ?

Comment: Kinda, I'm currently trying it this way: `<div class="bg"></div>` And the css is like you told me `background: url('shows/wayward_pines/img/bg.jpg') no-repeat center cover;`

Comment: @Timo , as StephanieQ said below, you cannot see the background of an element without it having actual dimensions to represent its scale. If the element is relative to other elements, you can set relative width and height for it in either percentages, ems, rems.. you call it. You can also set a height in `vh` (viewportheight) or width in `vw` (viewportwidth)

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that you can use "height" indeed and set it to **100**, but not **'%'** but **'vh'**.

```
height: 100vh;
```

Comment: You can also use `vw` (viewport width) to set the width. But both `vh` and `vw` can cause some unwanted behavior when it comes to being relative to other sections of your page.

Comment: Alright, didn't know that and will keep an eye on it. But it didn't work with '%' or 'px'. Is there maybe another unit which won't make any trouble?